# Simulate tab keypress when another key is pressed inside CKEditor widget

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm developing a simple CKEditor widget that has a table with some editable fields and does calculations with those values. When I showed it to the user, he requested that he changes fields with the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key instead of <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Basically, this is a sample of the widget structure (I needed to put divs inside the editable table cells because I could not make the cells themselves editable at the plugin initialization):

```
    '<div id="widget-wrapper">' +
                '<table>' +
                    '<tr>' +
                        '<td> Altura:</td>' +
                        '<td><div id="altura" class="edt single-line editable1"> </div> </td>' +
                        '<td> cm</td>' +
                    '</tr>' +

                    '<tr>' +
                        '<td> Peso:</td>' +
                        '<td><div id="peso" class="edt single-line editable2"> </div> </td>' +
                        '<td> kg</td>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                '</table>' +
    </div>
```

When I press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, I can switch through the two editable fields normally. In the docs, I saw this [method](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_dom_element.html#method-focusNext) that seems to do what I need. So I did this to focus the next element when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed, but the event seems to do nothing:

```
 editor.on( 'key', function( event ) {
    activeElement = editor.document.getActive();
    keycode = event.data.keyCode;

    if(keycode == 13) {
        activeElement.focusNext();
    }

});
```

Is there any other way to do what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your feature is almost ready to go. [`element.focusNext`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_dom_element.html#method-focusNext) function utilizes `tabindex` DOM Element attribute to switch between focusable elements. You should add this attribute to your output HTML. Also, don't forget to enable this attribute in [ACF](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_dom_element.html#method-focusNext) or it will be removed.

```
<div id="widget-wrapper">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td> Altura:</td>
      <td><div id="altura" class="edt single-line editable1" tabindex="1"> </div> </td>
      <td> cm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Peso:</td>
      <td><div id="peso" class="edt single-line editable2" tabindex="2"> </div> </td>
      <td> kg</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Also I think that it's good idea to cancel an enter event so it won't add new line on editable focus change.

```
config.allowedContent = 'div(editable1,editable2)[tabindex]';
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', config );

editor.on( 'key', function( event ) {
  activeElement = editor.document.getActive();
  keycode = event.data.keyCode;

   if( keycode == 13 ) {
     activeElement.focusNext();
     event.cancel();
   }
} );
```

Be aware that messing with enter key event will create an important issue - your users won't be able to create new line inside editable field.

Please, see working example https://codepen.io/jacekbogdanski/pen/ERNmEj

Comment: I never tought about tabindex being the issue because the tab key and the down arrow key were working perfectly. Adding the attribute to all my editable fields worked. Thanks for replying!